# Dynamically change height of iframe in typescript/angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe

I'm working on a cross-domain application that involves loading content into iframes. The problem is that we do not know the size of the content we are receiving and I would like to be able to dynamically change the height of the iframe to fit accordingly. However, all of the solutions I've found are centered around JavaScript but I'm working with TypeScript/Angular4.

I've tried accessing the DOM elements via `(load)` on the iframe but it doesn't return the iframe content, but the initial iframe size (prior to content being loaded).

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following directive to achieve this.

```
import { Directive , ElementRef , OnInit , Renderer } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
selector: '[iframeAutoHeight]'
})
export class IframeAutoHeightDirective implements OnInit {
private el: any;
private renderer: Renderer;
private prevHeight: number;
private sameCount: number;

constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _renderer: Renderer) {
    this.el = _elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.renderer = _renderer;
}

ngOnInit() {
    const self = this;
    if (this.el.tagName === 'IFRAME') {
        this.renderer.listen(this.el, 'load', () => {
            self.prevHeight = 0;
            self.sameCount = 0;
            setTimeout(() => {
                self.setHeight();
            }, 50);
        });
    }
}

setHeight() {
    const self = this;
    if (this.el.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight !== this.prevHeight) {
        this.sameCount = 0;
        this.prevHeight = this.el.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(
            self.el,
            'height',
            this.el.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight  + 'px'
        );
        setTimeout(() => {
            self.setHeight();
        }, 50);

    } else {
        this.sameCount++;
        if (this.sameCount < 2) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                self.setHeight();
            }, 50);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar app.  I just set the iframe height attribute to 100% and scrolling to auto.  Then in your outer app just have html and body set to 100% height and body overflow-y to hidden.

Comment: Are you sure about the height to 100%? According to W3 the height attribute only accepts pixel values (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_height.asp). I tried it anyway but still to no avail.